# Can't install Linux Mint16 on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, linux-mint

I am trying to install Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon on Oracle VirtualBox (4.2.12 if that matters). To that end I mounted the Mint iso and the Mint boot loader starts up with "Automatic boot in x seconds", but then the signature of BusyBox v1.20.2 shows up and I am confronted with an error:

```
error reading /lib/udev/hwdb.bin: No such file or directory`

Can not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on //filesystem.squashfs
```

I have installed prior versions of Mint in VirtualBox and the process was straightforward and painless. This time, I have no idea of how to proceed. Search didn't result in anything I could understand...

Comment: Did you check the MD5 or SHA checksum of the ISO? Does it help to re-create the virtual disk or to modify the controller options (type etc)?

Comment: @tohuwawohu Yes, and no.